# repeating-linear-gradient not visible in some browsers

Tags: css, firefox, webkit, linear-gradients

I'm trying to draw a grid as a background of a `div` element. I just like to use css, so I decided to use `repeating-linear-gradient`. However, it seems that browser react quite different to this and either draw only very thin lines or none at all (worst seems to be Chrome, but also Firefox on a Mac (v21) seems to have some problems). I've created a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/PwzNB/1/) (if you can't see anything, try another browser (Opera seems to do best) or resize the result window).

Is there anything wrong with the css code or does anyone know a workaround?
[image: Firefox v21 (Mac)]

### css

```css
.grid {
    background-image: 
        repeating-linear-gradient(to right, transparent 1px, transparent 39px, red 40px, red 40px),
        repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 1px, transparent 39px, red 40px, red 40px);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer (http://jsfiddle.net/PwzNB/4/):

```
.grid {
    background-size: 20px 20px;
    background-image: 
        repeating-linear-gradient(to right, transparent 1px, transparent 39px, red 40px, red 40px),
        repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 1px, transparent 39px, red 40px, red 40px);
}
```

Strangely enough, `background-size: 10px 10px;` will vary the grid size to `10x10` without changing the `background-image` attribute...

### Update

This is probably the version I will settle on. Grid dimensions are based on the size of the background image, so I just need to set `background-size` to adjust the grid size. [Jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/PwzNB/5/), some code here:

```
.grid {
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  background-image: 
    repeating-linear-gradient(to right, transparent, transparent calc(100% - 1px), red calc(100% - 1px), red 100%),
    repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent, transparent calc(100% - 1px), red calc(100% - 1px), red 100%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@orange is right that he found the solution for this, but keeping the `background-size: 20px 20px;` will vary in different resolutions. So my suggestion to do it the better way `background-size: 2em;` and that's all. But I think you should accept @orange answer.